# How do you install a repo by branchName and have it build when it installs?

Tags: git, npm, enterprise

I'm working in an enterprise repo and needed to install repos by branchName not by version. 
I was able to do this via:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:user/repo.git#yourBranchName
```

This will also work for the `https url from git`
After install though it looks like the build and dist directories are not included.
How do you install a repo by branchName and still have it built when it's installed?

```
One approach I've tried is building the repo and then removing the dist 
and lib directories form the .gitignore. This works but requires committing those directories 
to github.
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A great way to resolve this is to add a prepare script to the package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "builder run build"
}
```

We use builder and this worked beautifully. 
I'd imagine what ever command works for you locally to build would work in this prepare scripts as that is what worked for me.